# Using Structures and Pointers

Tags: c++, vector, structure

This code is supposed to read in from a file and store the information. Here's the file:

```
5 
Franks,Tom 2 3 8 3 6 3 5 
Gates,Bill 8 8 3 0 8 2 0 
Jordan,Michael 9 10 4 7 0 0 0 
Bush,George  5 6 5 6 5 6 5 
Heinke,Lonnie  7 3 8 7 2 5 7
```

right now I'm just focused on saving pointers to the names. Here's the code I have so far (Ignore the other functions I haven't gotten to those yet). I have to save the names using  employees[row] = new Employee; and           fin >> employees[row]->names; and I just don't know how to go about doing that.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Employee {
string names;
vector<int> data;
int totalHrs;
};


int fillAndTotal(vector<Employee *>&employees);   
void sort(vector<Employee *>&employees, int amount); 
void output(vector<Employee *>&employees, int amount); 



int main()
{
vector<Employee *>employees;
//vector<string>names;
int amount = 0;


amount = fillAndTotal(employees);

sort(employees, amount);

output(employees, amount);


system("pause");
return 0;

}

int fillAndTotal(vector<Employee *>&employees) {

int const TTL_HRS = 7;
ifstream fin;
fin.open("empdata.txt");

if (fin.fail()) {
    cout << "ERROR";
}

int sum = 0;
int numOfNames;
fin >> numOfNames;
string tmpString;
int tempInt = 0;

vector<int>temp(8);

for (int row = 0; row < numOfNames; row++) {

    employees[row] = new Employee; 

    fin >> employees[row]->names;
```

Comment: "I don't know how to go about doing that" is not a question. To the extend it is a question, the answer is: "read your C++ book and follow the examples in it for reading and processing from `std::cin`, and for using and managing vectors and structures".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've tried that. I've read over the lecture slides, the section of the textbook, and I've been messing with the code for the past hour and a half. I'm not coming on here looking for a straight up answer, but a little help would be nice.

Comment: When you've read the section of the textbook that describes how to use `std::vector`, how exactly did that section of your textbook explain one should go about adding new values to a vector? It can't be the way you do (or don't do) here. Start with that task: correctly adding new values to a vector. If you can't even do that, forget about populating the actual contents of the object.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well I've written this code before with vectors and I just used push_back. I can't use that now because the names aren't in a vector they're just in the structure...right?

Comment: No matter what's in a vector, the process for adding objects to a vector is exactly the same. Whether a vector contains an `int`, a `std::string`, or a `Employee *`, the process for adding whatever it is, to the vector, is still the same.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ok but names aren't in a vector

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm starting to get it. So I'm treating the whole structure like a pointer?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik am I really so stupid that you can't even be bothered to reply to me? Damn, rip me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need pointers for this - your Employee structure is perfectly safe to store as-in in a vector.

Secondly, when reading line-orientated data like this, it's very easy to get off-track and let your reads overflow into the next line, or underflow and you not carry out enough reads for the line - what I do is write a function that reads a whole line at a time and returns a stringstream containing just that line, then I do my individual reads on that stringstream.

Thirdly, and finally, it's always useful to write functions that allows you to dump out your data structures so that you can confirm visually that you've populated the structures correctly. Or you can use a debugger.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Employee
{
    std::string names;
    std::vector<int> data;
    int totalHrs;
};
using EmpList = std::vector<Employee>;

int fillAndTotal(EmpList& employees);
std::stringstream readRowData(std::istream& fin);

#ifndef NDEBUG
// Debug - dump to stream.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Employee& employee);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const EmpList& employees);
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    EmpList employees;

    auto grandTotal = fillAndTotal(employees);
    std::cout << employees;
    std::cout << "\nGrand total hours: " << grandTotal << std::endl;
}

int fillAndTotal(EmpList& employees)
{
    auto fin = std::ifstream("empdata.txt");

    auto rowCount = 0;
    auto rowData = readRowData(fin);
    rowData >> rowCount;

    auto totalHours = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    {
        rowData = readRowData(fin);
        if (!fin.eof())
        {
            auto employee = Employee{};

            rowData >> employee.names;

            int hours;
            while (rowData >> hours)
            {
                if (hours != 0)
                {
                    employee.data.push_back(hours);
                    employee.totalHrs += hours;
                    totalHours += hours;
                }
            }

            employees.push_back(employee);
        }
    }
    return totalHours;
}

std::stringstream readRowData(std::istream& fin)
{
    std::stringstream rowStream;
    std::string rowData;
    if (getline(fin, rowData))
    {
        rowStream.str(rowData);
    }
    return rowStream;
}

#ifndef NDEBUG
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Employee& employee)
{
    out << "Name: " << employee.names << '\n';
    out << "Total hours: " << employee.totalHrs << '\n';
    out << "Individual hours:";
    for (auto const &hours : employee.data)
    {
        out << ' ' << hours;
    }
    out << std::endl;
    return out;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const EmpList& employees)
{
    auto first = true;
    for (auto const &employee : employees)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            out << '\n';
        }
        out << employee;
    }
    return out;
}
#endif
```

Now your output function is already written for you, and you just need to write your sort.